# How to play Geovision video files in Ubuntu

Tags: video, vlc, codecs, file-format

I will need to playback some video that was made in a [Geovision video camera](http://www.geovision.com.tw/english/3_1_IPcam.asp) which has its own format.

I was told that there may not be a way to play them in VLC or any other because the video file is made with a propietary codec. Looking in the "*internets*" I only see [old forum posts](http://forum.videohelp.com/threads/359426-Problems-with-AVI-file-in-Linux) about how to try and do this, but nothing that is very certain.

Does anyone have experience with this file format in ubuntu and know how to play them?

Comment: Vlc is very popular, but mplayer might be the Linux media player which supports the most codecs. Mplayer has been superseeded by Mplayer2, and then mpv. I read that Windows media player and Winamp can play those files, and the codecs can be downloaded. Maybe an idea to run one of those programs with PlayOnLinux (WINE) ? https://ffmpeg.org/pipermail/ffmpeg-user/2013-October/017908.html (from 2013).  http://www.usavisionsys.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=109

Answer (score 0):

There is a sample geovision file on the MPlayer sample site that can be downloaded as follows:

```
wget samples.mplayerhq.hu/V-codecs/GAVC/GeoVision_camera.avi
```

This file plays quite easily with SMPlayer:

```
sudo apt-get install smplayer
```

Below is a screenshot of this file playing quite successfully on my own system:

[image]

Not a very exciting film clip I am afraid but you get the idea :).

Comment: Unfortunately I couldn't make it play on SMPlayer. Here is the error log:

Requested video codec family [geomp4] (vfm=vfw) not available.
Enable it at compilation.
Cannot find codec matching selected -vo and video format 0x34504D47.

Comment: @luisgonzalez Seems odd as recent MPlayer / SMPlayer simply uses ffh264 for this particular  file.  What does the command: `mplayer | head -n 1` show? As well the version of SMPlayer (seen in: Help --> About SMPlayer)